# Can i change the uid of a user in /etc/passwd file

Tags: linux, permissions, rhel, amazon-linux, chrony

I have an issue running RabbitMQ docker container as it needs uid:gid (999:999) however chrony NTP service is already running with that gid(999) and is conflicting.

Can I change the gid from /etc/passwd file for chrony? does it affect anything?

Comment: why would it need to run as a specific UID:GID?

Comment: (yes you can. But the files owned by the user will not change ownership! So you break almost everything.)

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to change the user used by the RabbitMQ service by configuring it properly.

Comment: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Xray its  mandatory for jfrog xray service.
I have reached out to them as well

Answer (score 1):

usermod <your_user_name_here> -u <new_user_id_here>
groupmod <you_group_name_same_as_username_here> -g <new_group_id_here>

you must have to check if chronyd is using these user/group with their ID in the config files, if that is the case you should change the IDs in config files as well & restart the service. DO NOT DIRECTLY MODIFY PASSWD

example:

check the ID against user:

```
  grep -i myuser /etc/passwd
  myuser:x:504:504::/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

change the user ID

```
usermod myuser -u 5555
```

check the changes of user ID

```
grep -i myuser /etc/passwd
myuser:x:5555:504::/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

check the primary group ID

```
grep -i myuser /etc/group
myuser:x:504:
```

change the primary group ID

```
groupmod myuser -g 5555
```

verify the changes

```
grep -i myuser /etc/group
myuser:x:5555:

grep -i myuser /etc/passwd
myuser:5555:5555::/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```